# How to force g++ to respect #define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, g++

I need to use `strerror_r` to translate error numbers into human readable messages compiled with **g++** on Linux Debian Bullseye. The man page notes:

```
int strerror_r(int errnum, char *buf, size_t buflen);
           /* XSI-compliant */

char *strerror_r(int errnum, char *buf, size_t buflen);
           /* GNU-specific */

strerror_r():
   The XSI-compliant version is provided if:
   (_POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200112L) && !  _GNU_SOURCE
   Otherwise, the GNU-specific version is provided.
```

We have two different types of the return value: `int` or `char*` depending on the version defined by _POSIX_C_SOURCE. I have this small test program:

```
~$ cat strerror_r.c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// #define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L
// #undef _GNU_SOURCE

#define ERROR_BUFFER_LEN (size_t)256

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
#if _POSIX_C_SOURCE < 200112L
    char* ret;
#else
    int ret;
#endif
    char errorBuffer[ERROR_BUFFER_LEN];
    int errno;

    errno = 0;
    ret = strerror_r(errno, errorBuffer, ERROR_BUFFER_LEN);
    fprintf(stderr, "Error message by pointer = '%s'\n", ret);
    fprintf(stderr, "Content of errorBuffer =  '%s'\n", errorBuffer);

    return 0;
}
```

If I compile it with **gcc** everything is as expected:

```
$ gcc strerror_r.c && ./a.out; rm a.out
Error message by pointer = '(null)'
Content of errorBuffer =  'Success'
```

If I compile it with **g++** I get this:

```
$ g++ strerror_r.c && ./a.out; rm a.out
strerror_r.c: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
strerror_r.c:24:21: error: invalid conversion from ‘char*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
   24 |     ret = strerror_r(errno, errorBuffer, ERROR_BUFFER_LEN);
      |           ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                     |
      |                     char*
rm: cannot remove 'a.out': No such file or directory
```

If I try to force the needed version by uncommenting

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L
#undef _GNU_SOURCE
```

I get:

```
$ g++ strerror_r.c && ./a.out; rm a.out
strerror_r.c:7: warning: "_POSIX_C_SOURCE" redefined
    7 | #define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L
      |
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/string.h:26,
                 from strerror_r.c:3:
/usr/include/features.h:281: note: this is the location of the previous definition
  281 | # define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
      |
strerror_r.c: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
strerror_r.c:24:21: error: invalid conversion from ‘char*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
   24 |     ret = strerror_r(errno, errorBuffer, ERROR_BUFFER_LEN);
      |           ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                     |
      |                     char*
rm: cannot remove 'a.out': No such file or directory
```

What I'm missing here? Why **g++** does not compile the default thread save version of `strerror_r`? I need that version. How can I fix it?

**Reference**

- [Feature Test Macros](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the `#define` and `#undef` directives before you include any header files, so the first few lines should look like this:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L
#undef _GNU_SOURCE

#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

That's because those header files or internal header files they include need those values defined to choose the proper variant.  If you define them after including the headers, the headers don't see the right values and they don't include the version you want.

Often people specify these values on the command like with the `-D` and `-U` arguments so they are always specified before header files are included.

Comment: I know that these directives have to be at the very first position as noted at [Feature Test Macros](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html). I set it in the example behind the #include directives to show by the error message that it is already predefined. But by all try and error I've overseen to set also #undef  _GNU_SOURCE at the first position :-{ Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: Just checked more details. Because POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L is already defined as shown by the error message, it is sufficient to set only #undef _GNU_SOURCE at the first position or use the `-U_GNU_SOURCE` compiler option.